# phpDoc notation to specify return type identical to parameter type

Tags: php, polymorphism, phpstorm, phpdoc, late-binding

Imagine the following hypothetical class structure, not an all too uncommon scenario with all PHPdoc hinting set up correctly:

```
class BaseFilter {
  /** ...base methods... */
}

class TextFilter extends BaseFilter {
  public function setMinLength($len)
  {
    /** ...irrelevant */
  }
}

class SomethingWithFilters
{
  /**
   * @param BaseFilter $filter A valid filter to be added.
   * @return BaseFilter The filter that was added for easy chaining
   */
  public function addFilter(BaseFilter $filter)
  {
    $this->filters[] = $filter;
    return $filter;
  }

  /** @var BaseFilter[] A list of filters */
  private $filters = [];
}
```

Now I use this code as follows:

```
$myClass = new SomethingWithFilters();
$myClass->addFilter(new TextFilter())->setMinLength(8);
```

In phpStorm (and probably most other IDEs since it makes sense) the second line produces a warning, stating that `BaseFilter` does not contain a method `setMinLength`. While absolutely correct, this is intended polymorphism behaviour, fully utilizing PHP's late binding characteristics - in a language like C# you'd have to upcast explicitly. As such I would expect phpDoc syntax to support some kind of dynamic notation here, stating that the return type for `addFilter` is identical to the `$filter` type supplied.

I have tried changing it to:

```
@return $filter
```

But this just shows up as a reference to `BaseFilter` and is treated as such, still giving the warning.

Is there any standardized way to achieve this effect, in such a way that at least the common IDEs can understand it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best an IDE could do here would be if your @return on addFilter() actually listed all the possible BaseFilter children that could be returned:

```
@return BaseFilter|TextFilter|AnotherFilter
```

This *might* trigger your IDE into providing all the possible methods for all those possible return classes.  It depends on whether or not the IDE in use knows how to recognize such a list of possible return types.  Obviously this would get tedious on your part though, putting such a list in many return tags.

I do not know of any IDE that would look at your return type of BaseFilter alone, generate a list of all possible parent+child methods, and thus make that whole list available for autocompletion **automagically**.

Comment: Well the point is that if I define `@return $filter` the IDE will know exactly what type I'm passing as that parameter already, and could thus fill it in. Listing all filters is not an option inside a framework as someone else might create a new one. Thanks for the input though  :)

Comment: `@return $filter` has no meaning to an IDE because $filter has no value except when the code is actually running

Comment: The current options in phpDocumentor 2.x for @return in fluent methods is "return self", "return static", and "return $this". The current implementation is simple, as all three act the same, but eventually they will mean three distinct things.  As an aside, I started to say I'd avoid this issue entirely by doing "$x = new TextFilter(); $x->setMinLength(8); addFilter($x);", but I was guessing that was only a peripheral concern :-)

Comment: @ashnazg I'm indeed aware that an extra line of code solves it, but that kind of defeats the point of chaining calls :) I should probably suggest this for addition to phpDoc standards.

Comment: @MarkBaker that's not correct - when I invoke `$myClass->addFilter(new TextFilter())` the IDE knows perfectly well what polymorphic type is in `$filter`. It can as such also perfectly well parse `@return $filter` properly, and fall back to `BaseFilter` if a more precise type cannot be determined from context, as it already does in all other cases where exact type is unclear because of missing docs or context.